Nas storage temporary file errors
We have a NAS storage used for file sharing linux+windows.
This is old server, but it supports Samba dialect of 3.0 and we use it.
This is the relevant line in /etc/fstsb:
//nas1/Work         /nas1/Work     cifs mfsymlinks,auto,_netdev,exec,uid=0,credentials=/etc/.smbpass,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,cache=none,dir_mode=0777,noperm,vers=3 0 0

When we mount the storage in the Linux we have weird problems occasionally this happens:

When we try to access file/s we receives "Host is Down", "Resource temporarily unavailable", "Bad file descriptor", "No such a file or directory"... When we retry to access the same file again it appears and everything is OK.
Copying files in linux results in different md5 checksum sometimes. I remove the file, copy it from windows and then everything works and the file has the same md5 checksum in the target location.
There are errors in /proc/fs/cifs/Stats:


\nas1\Work SMBs: 38327115 Bytes read: 147002485177  Bytes written:
13754417376 Open files: 2 total (local), 0 open on server
TreeConnects: 7103 total 0 failed TreeDisconnects: 0 total 0 failed
Creates: 3781492 total 25 failed Closes: 3771250 total 10813 failed
Flushes: 42546 total 0 failed Reads: 13005190 total 246 failed Writes:
14122424 total 208 failed Locks: 0 total 0 failed IOCTLs: 4408 total 2
failed QueryDirectories: 157598 total 17 failed ChangeNotifies: 0
total 0 failed QueryInfos: 3335551 total 0 failed SetInfos: 102218
total 1 failed OplockBreaks: 54 sent 0 failed

Additional notes:

dmesg - has no issues/logs with the CIFS, nas1
This happens both on Ubuntu 22.04 and on much older machine with Centos 7.
In windows, I haven't accounted any problems.
I'm pretty sure the storage is OK, no warnings in the storage machine.

Anywhere to look for more details? Reference, ideas?

I think: https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/ are better places to ask, because the question is off-topic here.
